# How to resolve the error - HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error reading field value:

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We have a system which uses AWS Kinesis Firehose, Glue, S3, etc. We get JSON payloads on Kinesis Firehose which stores them in a S3 location. One of the fields is epoch_utc. Once stored in S3, we run Glue crawler on this S3 and derive the schema of table. The Athena table created has epoch_utc column with data type bigint. We can query the data in s3 by running queries on this Athena table. Lets call this Athena table as events.

Now for one day, it seems the value of epoch_utc seems very large. We have a query which is failing to run for a given data with below error. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT event_id,
                        event_date,
                        row_number() over (
                            partition BY event_id
                            ORDER BY epoch_utc
                        ) AS row_number
                    FROM events
                    WHERE
                        "event_date" <= '2023-10-08'
                        AND "event_date" >= '2023-10-07'
                        AND event_id IS NOT NULL
```

When we run the query we get the error:

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error reading field value: For input string: "1.696652344251004E12"
```

I am also not able to run the query like:

```
select epoch_utc from events
where event_date = '2023-10-08'
order by epoch_utc desc
limit 200
```

Here I am also getting same error.

How can I clean the data from s3 if we are also not able to query the data? The epoch_utc seems to be giving this error.